# How can I change a button's text in Android Studio, when it's clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick

I'm doing I sports app that gives a score. How can I create a button that will tell the amount of downs in an American Football game. I want when the user clicks that button for each team, that it will say "1st down", then "2nd down", "3rd down", then "4th down", and then be reset back to "1st down" when "4th down" is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count=count+1;
            String text=String.valueOf(count).concat("down");
            button.setText(text);
        }
    });
```

may be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity xml file (e.g activity_main.xml)

```
 <input onclick="change()" type="button" value="1st    Down" id=myButton"></input>
```

in your activity class (e.g MainActivity)

```
   function change() 
 {
var elem = document.getElementById("myButton");

if (elem.value=="1st Down"){
        elem.value = "2nd Down";

    } else if (elem.value = "2nd Down"){ 
        elem.value = "3rd Down"; 

    }else if (elem.value = "3rd Down"){ 
        elem.value = "4th Down";

    }else if (elem.value = "4th Down"){
        elem.value = "1st Down";  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this be as a string.xml or style.xml?

Comment: should this be as a string.xml or style.xml?

Comment: myButton defined in your layout xml if it's MainActivity then it should be activity_main.xml

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm probably not at the level yet where I know how to use <input/> in xml. Should it be <Button android:onClick="change()", android:type="button", android:value="1st", android:id="myButton"?

Answer (score -1):

if digits id low use of this else!use a String array

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("1");
        if(button.getText.ToString == "2th...."){
          //set 3
         }if(button.getText.ToString == "3..."){
          //set 4
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it only goes to 2nd Down. Maybe because in the xml I have the text as "1st Down" and then in java the setText is "2nd Down"      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myButton.setText("2nd Down");
            if(myButton.getText() == "3rd Down"){
                //set 3
            }if(myButton.getText() == "4th Down"){
                //set 4
            }
        }